# What triggers an intermediate result in the streaming API of Google Cloud Speech?

Tags: google-cloud-speech

It seems to be a specific number of seconds of silence, but I haven't found a definitive answer on this.

Answer (score 0):

This detail is not publicly available in the documentation. Since the [interim_results](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#streaming-recognition) are used on streaming requests to get partial translation during the streaming, my guess is that it is not a straight-forward rule but most likely is related to the ML model used, so it would be hard to identify the exact triggers for every different situation.

Nonetheless, I'm wondering why you would need to know the relation between what's ocurring with the audio and interim result during a streaming request. For example, if you want to split the requests and translations for every time the speaker pause, you could use [`single_utterance=true`](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1#streamingrecognitionconfig) for every request.

Comment: I'm using the streaming api to issue voice commands. And I would like to know when to expect interim results. If I use their sample code using single_utterance doesn't achieve the same results as not using them. When not using them, I get complete phrases after some silence. And it would be ideal to know what this pause is just for documentation purposes (My users would know that after a certain amound of silence the command will be processed).

Comment: I got it @edmz. I went ahead and created an Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/171962092) asking the Speech API team to share the info you're looking for. Feel free to subscribe to it to follow its updates.

Comment: Regarding your use case, it does sound like an ideal use case to be used with the [command_and_search model](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/transcription-model#transcription_models)  and `single_utterance=true` so I'm wondering what kind of results you're getting to consider the interim results to provide better accuracy for you. You could create a new issue tracker or SO question to check that; nonetheless, in the meantime, hope the issue tracker asking for the interim_results info helps you